# PHP - Formatting multible variables into a mysql DATETIME format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My script receives multiple variables from the user. Each variable has part of the date/time (year,month,day,hour,min). All the info is stored in separate variables.

I would like to format all that into an acceptable MySQL DATETIME format so it can be saved in a DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) functions are helpful here. Without an example of what you're working with, I can't give you a better example than the links.

Then you'd format your timestamp with [date()](http://php.net/date):

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: I had learned form other stackoverflow questions that date() would make the proper formatted timestamp, but I didn't know how to put it into something date() will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want

```
function getDBTime($year, $month, $day $hours, $mins, $secs = "0"){
    $timestamp = mktime($hours, $mins, $secs, $month, $day, $year); 
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp); 
}
```

and to use $var = getDBTime({your data here});

Comment: Same thing I posted 15 minutes ago. :)

Comment: @dtbarne Sorry, didn't see it when I started (slow internets) :)